# All items not removed from brewing stand in automated brewing system

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making an automated brewing system and it works well for most part. The items are being added to the brewing stand in the correct order and another hopper is adding bottles of water. there is a hopper at the bottom with a chest to remove the finished potions.

**Problem:**

When brewing is done, I must press a button which will reset the system. The finished potions are to be removed (from all three slots) and then a new water bottle takes its place and then the materials are released again.

In my one, when I press the button, only the first slot is being removed from the brewing stand and two others remain. In addition, I am seeing fresh bottles of water also going through the system and into the chest.

Am I missing something? Please let me know what you think.

Thank You!

**Edit:**

Solution:

So what @Aiyion.Prime said was the problem. The top hopper seems to be filling in as fast as the bottom one is removing, which results in only one slot being filled/emptied.

As @MrLemon mentioned in the comment, it is possible to fix this issue with my one button setup. All you need to do it take the signal going to the bottom hopper and split it to another lead. Then invert the signal so that when the bottom is shut the top is open and visa versa. Then use your favorite method to extend the signal gogin to the top hopper. I used the multiple repeater method, splitting the red stone wire into multiple parts and having a single repeater on each, having one+ delay than the previous, with all repeaters joining at the end to make a single signal going to the top hopper. -- this will power the hopper as soon as the signal comes, but because each hopper is on a 1 tick delay, and I had 4-5 repeaters, I was able to keep the signal going for 5 ticks (longer than a regular signal).

I also added a 1 tic delay on the signal going to the bottom hopper so give the top hopper time to shut before emptying the bottom, and then after the bottom one shuts (is powered), the top one can open again and refill the brewing stand with water bottles.

I hope that helps anyone else with the same problem as me and thank to those who answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are missing something ;)

The solution is the game mechanics:
The hopper which is leading new bottles in your brewing stand is -always- faster than the hopper leading out.
Which means, before the cleaning-hopper below hast the chance to clear the second slot, the top one has already refilled the first.
The only way to avoid this, is to build another lever or button connected to the top hopper. (if you want to use buttons, use an inverter in between)

I got this problem a few weeks ago, i hooked up the two hoppers to a single redstone-clock-system to fully automate splashpotions of harming, which works fine for me :)

Comment: It should be doable using a single button, but you have to make sure that this button locks the water bottle supply hopper at least as long as the finished potion hopper is unlocked, and watch out for signal delay.

Comment: Ok Thank You! That was Exatly what I was looking for. I will add what it did to my answer.